# How to Insert data automatically in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Here i need to insert data record automatically in Database using Yii2 when the condition met

i have two table `claim` and `pending`

In claim table i have 10 fields including i have another field called `turnaroundtime` here i will set a date

if the claim table doesn't update on or before the `turnaroundtime`, then some  data from the claim table have to move to another table called `pending`.

How can i achieve this using Yii 2 Framework

**Note:** In claim table i also have `created_at` and `updated_at` fields also

Answer (score 2):

you should set a cronjob to run on certain interval of time to invoke some php code that would check the difference between current time, turnaroundtime and updated_at time and move the data to pending table if the condition is met

```
if((current-time >= turnaroundtime) && (updated_at > turnaroundtime)){
    //move data to pending table
}
```

Comment: thank you very much its working , how can i everytime run cmd prompt

Comment: You need to set cron job working an interval time.
If it's unix server, run `crontab -e` to set the cron job.

Comment: http://docs.phplist.com/CronJobExamples.html.  http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml. cronjobs are provided by webservers. If cronjobs are enabled in cpanel you can see it under Advanced tab. If you like this answer please don't forget to upvote my answer !!

Answer (score 1):

in Yii2 [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html) you can use this [beforeSave](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeSave()-detail) event.

> This method is called at the beginning of inserting or updating a
>   record.

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if($insert) { 
        // If data is new
        $this->created_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    } else { 
        //It's updating
        $this->updated_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
    }

    //Make sure you return true because it's an event
    return true;
}
```